# How do I remove the postgres user

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

I am on a windows 10 computer, and am looking to clean up my system as I have had this machine for a while, and it has quite a bit of "junk" on it.

I believe part of this is the postgres use in my users folder. I had used this PC while studying computer science, and am 99% sure I had installed postgresql on it at some point. Is this a user I can remove? If so, how? It always says I the folder is being used, but I do not see postgresql in any of my installed programs or even startup programs list.

Is this a required user I just did not notuice in the past?